# What custom themes are there for Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

Where can I find custom themes for Django's admin app, other than [django-grappelli](http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/)?

Comment: Sadly your options are very limited. Django admin theming has not picked up much traction. Most of the django themes are not really good, It takes quite abit of time investment to roll your own. I have put to together a comparsion perhaps it may be useful to others looking for themes to leverage on. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5QKi4Vt-uE

Answer (score 15):

There is a wiki chart displaying a large list of admin interfaces, with a contrast of features, maintenance, etc...

http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/admin-interface/

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you [Admin Tools](https://github.com/django-admin-tools/django-admin-tools). I like it because it's highly customizable and well documented.

Answer (score 3):

Well, other than grapielli, there is also a mobile admin, for the iPhone:
  http://github.com/jezdez/django-mobileadmin

Comment: but this is for mobile site i think so ...

Answer (score 0):

sorl-curator

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=sorl-curator&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8